# Sri Krishna's Weighing

Tags: scripture, krishna, daana

As the title goes, [**Sri Krishna Tulabharam**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Krishna_Tulabharam), it's a movie made on the very act of Weighing by Scale of Lord Krishna.
*This story, as also heard by me in several Srimad Bhagvad Puran Katha, is generally used in the context of emphasizing the fact that the only thing greater than God is the pure love and devotion of a devotee towards God.*

For those who might not know, [**Tulabhara**, also known as Tula-purusha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulabhara) is an ancient Hindu practice in which a person is weighed against a commodity (such as gold, grain, fruits or other objects), and the equivalent weight of that commodity is offered as donation. The article in the Wikipedia very well establishes this practice as predominant in the past as per Hindu mythology and Indian history too.

As the story goes, as per the mentioned films' [plotline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Krishna_Tulabharam#Plot) as follows:

> Lord Krishna reaches heaven along with Satyabhama, confronts with
> Lord Indra (Rajanala), acquires Parijat tree and gifts it to
> Satyabhama. As a result, the pride in Satyabhama increases tenfold and
> looks low at Krishna's remaining wives. Knowing everything, Lord
> Krishna acts as innocent and silently plays drama with Narada. After
> that, on the occasion of Rukmini's birthday, she invites Krishna and
> Satyabhama to take her hospitality. Satyabhama does not allow Krishna,
> but Krishna yields towards Rukmini's devotion and goes along with her.
> Now Satyabhama becomes depressed for her defeat and she wants to
> achieve Krishna's love totally for herself. Sage Narada takes
> advantage of the situation and provokes Satyabhama to perform a
> ritual. **The main concept of the ritual is that Satyabhama must donate
> her husband Krishna along with the Parijat tree and she can get back
> him by repaying with the gold of his weight.** Arrogant Satyabhama feels
> that she can easily weigh her husband with her wealth. So, without any
> hesitation, she donates Krishna to Sage Narada, but the situation
> becomes reversed, **Satyabhama is unable to outweigh Krishna, even after
> using her entire wealth**. Sage Narada takes Lord Krishna along with him
> and starts selling him on the streets. Seeing this, the Dwaraka people
> become violent and try to crush Narada. Lord Krishna stops them when
> Krishna's remaining wives come forward, ask Narada to take their
> entire wealth and leave their husband. Here, Sage Narada explains that
> no one has understood the real form of Krishna, he is a lord who will
> yield only for devotion. Sage Narada also says that there is only one
> person in this universe who can weigh Lord Krishna that is none other
> than Rukmini. ***Ultimately, Satyabhama's pride completely comes to an
> end and she brings Rukmini by falling on her feet. Finally, Rukmini
> weighs Krishna with one Tulasidalam (Basil leaf) and gets him back,***
> while Satyabhama also realizes the real form of the Lord and becomes
> his devotee.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulabhara#Legendary) part of the article on  makes a subtle reference to the same story.

**So, my question being about the Scriptural References for this story?
Which all scriptures mention this incident?**

Also, are there any other similar instances or puranic stories (need not be based on the same practice of Tulabharam) described in the scriptures, where a Husband or Wife (or anyone of kith and kin type) makes such kind of philanthropic benefaction based dharmic donation i.e dāna (दान) to anyone?

Answer (score 5):

> Also, are there any other similar instances (need not be based on the
> same practice of Tulabharam) described in the scriptures, where a
> Husband or Wife (or anyone of kith and kin type) makes such kind of
> philanthropic benefaction based dharmic donation i.e dāna (दान) to
> anyone?

Tulapurusha is mentioned as one of the most effective sin cleansing measures in Parashara Smriti's 12th Chapter:

> 80. The chandrayana penance, the eating of unripe barley, the form of making a gift, called the Tulapurusha, [I, e., making a gift of such a
>     quantity of any substance as is equal in weight to a male human
>     being], and the act of walking behind cows, — these put an end to all
>     kinds of sin.

(NOTE:- This is only a partial answer)